# Looking for elegant way to see if two mysql columns have the same order

Tags: mysql

I need to search a mysql table to see if values are increasing by date.

For example

[image]

as opposed to

[image]

Obviously I can sort the table by date and read the records one by one to see if the values are in order, but I was thinking there ought to be some way to do this all within mysql.  However I can't come up with a strategy that will do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Mysql version 5.6.45

Comment: what does it matter, you can sort them at runtime, it will not cost that much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by self-joining the table on `timestamp` being the next highest `timestamp`, and then taking the minimum of the differences between `value` of those rows. If the minimum is > 0 (or >= 0 if you want to allow consecutive values to be the same), then the values are in order.

```
SELECT MIN(d1.value - COALESCE(d2.value, 0)) > 0 AS in_order
FROM data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.t = (SELECT MAX(t) 
                             FROM data d
                             WHERE d.t < d1.t)
```

For your first sample data, this gives `in_order = 1`, for the second, `in_order = 0`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8c88c3dba121d572b713d00834026371)